# PHP cannot run a python script that uses ffmpeg (when the python script runs in terminal)

Tags: python, php, apache, web, ffmpeg

In my website, a user uploads an audio file that gets mixed by a python script. The python script uses ffmpeg to translate the files, however it doesn't work when I try executing via php due to ffmpeg, I get this error

usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work")

The python script can run (with no errors) in the Linux terminal and ffmpeg can run separately also in the terminal (in the website's directory).

I have tried linking the environment with php with putenv("/usr/bin/ffmpeg") which had no luck, as well as linking to the usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ directory in the same way, also no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error is because to pydub [cannot find ffmpeg](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/utils.py#L170).  You should make sure that the location of `ffmpeg` is one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable and can be found by [pydub's which method](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/utils.py#L156).

Comment: if I type "which ffmpeg" into the terminal, it loads ffmpeg, and it loads with python when the script is activated in the terminal too. ffmpeg is a path in my linux machine. It just doesn't work when activated with php

Comment: The PATH that you have from your shell is probably not the same as the path used by your python script.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I've switched to using the popen() php function but there's still the ffmpeg issue